# select every nth row in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, rowid

I am trying to select every nth row in SQL. I have been looking around Stack Overflow and piece together what I can based on my limited SQL knowledge. I have a table that has 81,225 rows. I am trying to select every 285th row in SQLite.

What I am using is as follows:

```
    Select *
    From Test A
    Where ROWID  > 0 AND ROWID <= 81225
    AND ROWID % 285 = 285 % 285
```

This query is giving me 285 rows (which i would expect), but it's not giving me the expected results. Is there something that needs to be added/changed to this code to give me the desired results?

Thank you,

Comment: Using the `rowid` for this works only if the values are consecutive, i.e., if no rows were deleted.

Answer (score 7):

The condition you are using for the modulus is wrong.  Use this instead:

```
Select *
From Test A
Where ROWID  > 0 AND ROWID <= 81225
AND ROWID % 285 = 0
```